# Is 'container.insight' namespace supported for AKS cluster in azure gov cloud?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am trying to fetch metrics from 'container.insight' namespace for Azure AKS cluster in gov cloud.
I have enabled container insights for the cluster, I can see data under insights tab but unable to find the namespace in metrics tab.

Is the namespace not available in gov cloud?

If not, how can I fetch the insight metrics via REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to fetch metrics from namespace 'container.insights/' which will be available as custom namespace with custom metrics in AKS when container insights is enabled for Azure AKS cluster.

As of now, custom metrics are only supported in public cloud regions (`https://<azure_region_code>.monitoring.azure.com`) as per this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-update-metrics).

Answer reference : [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-custom-overview#supported-regions)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.